# AngularJS - share a websocket between tabs/windows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, notifications, web-notifications

I am using [angular-websocket](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket) to open a WebSocket, The application is waiting for a message and then displays a web notification.

I noticed that when there is more than 1 tab open there are many connections and then every tab will receive a message and notifications will be displayed `1 X TABS_NUM` when it should be displayed once.

I think that to make it work properly I need to open 1 WebSocket for the whole app.

Any ideas? What should I do in that case?

Comment: Each window is a separate instance of your client side app. Really not clear what behavior you are looking for

Comment: I have a websocket that send notifications. But It is not right to send 2 of the same notification for the client if he have 2 open tabs... what should I do in that case

Comment: can't you just emit a message when it is read in one tab and other tab then knows about it?

Comment: @charlietfl can you please explain more ?

Comment: Are you using [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Receiving_notification_of_clicks_on_app_notifications)? If so can `tag` notifications to avoid duplicates also. If not ... show more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Receiving_notification_of_clicks_on_app_notifications) solved my issue:

> It is usually undesirable for a user to receive a lot of notifications
>   in a short space of time — for example, what if a messenger
>   application notified a user for each incoming message, and they were
>   being sent a lot? To avoid spamming the user with too many
>   notifications, it's possible to modify the pending notifications
>   queue, replacing single or multiple pending notifications with a new
>   one.
>
> To do this, it's possible to add a tag to any new notification. If a
>   notification already has the same tag and has not been displayed yet,
>   the new notification replaces that previous notification. If the
>   notification with the same tag has already been displayed, the
>   previous notification is closed and the new one is displayed.

```
new Notification(notificationMessage.title, {tag: notificationMessage._id});
```